# Cordova - Issue navigating some links in a Confluence/Gliffy diagram opened with InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, confluence, gliffy

I am building a Cordova Application that allows to browse an Atlassian Confluence site containing navigable diagrams. My diagrams are built with Gliffy and I want to navigate from one page to another via clickable diagram elements. I realized such navigation structure and it works fine in browsers. You can check it out at [this link](http://51.255.206.207:8090/display/MM/M_StructureItem) (click on M_Function).

In my Cordova app I am using InAppBrowser and, after a login screen, I am redirecting to a page of my mobile-oriented website (again, an Atlassian Confluence site) this way:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://51.255.206.207:8090/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1245261' + page, '_self', 'location=no');
```

On my website, I have menus and diagrams. When I click on menu items, everything works correctly, but when I click on the clickable shapes from the diagrams, I get an error (the page does not exist).

What's wrong with Confluence/Gliffy links? What's the difference between the app and the browser?

Or, at lease, how do I get to know the URL I am trying to reach from the app?

Comment: What device are you running the Cordova app on? Do you get any js console errors?

Comment: I am running on Android, but I also tested on Chrome. When using Chrome, it works fine, though. The HTML link  looks like <a href="/x/SQAT" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">M_Function</a>